# How to use machine learning to ask users dynamically and recommend a result

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification, recommendation-engine

I want to devolope a system which recommends a sport after asking multiple questions to an user. Which questions are asked and their fittest sorting should be decided dynamically by the system so that the best answer for each user is found.

I have a threefold data structure: sports are linked to different attributes and questions can refer to several attributes. Both relations are weighted.

On a scale from 0-1, soccer is linked to 'indoors' with 0.6, but to 'outdoors' with 0.8, as soccer is played more often outdoors and with 1.0 to 'ball' which is in any case necessary for soccer. Question 2 is linked to 'racket'(0.7) and 'bow' (0.6) as both items can be used with hands, however 'racket' is heigher weighted as it is more likely that someone thinks of 'racket' answering this question.

```
# table1: sports (result set)
1 | badminton
2 | soccer
3 | fishing

# table2: attributes (describes different results)
1 | indoors
2 | outdoors
3 | ball
4 | racket
5 | bow

# table3: questions (checks for needed attributes)
1 | Do you like doing sports outdoors?
2 | Do you want to hold a gadget while performing the sport?
```

I could try to build this based on a relational database and some ranking system implemented by me in python / pandas. However, I feel like I am neglecting recent developments in machine learning and apparently one should not build a recommendation engine for smaller projects by yourself:

> http://www.datacommunitydc.org/blog/2013/05/recommendation-engines-why-you-shouldnt-build-one

As far as I understood this could be partially a decission tree problem, am I right?

> http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

What is the concise problem statement of my matter in terms of machine learning? Which libraries could support me in my python-pandas environment?

*I am really sorry for being that naive, I promise to learn as much as I can if someone could guide me towards the right direction (regarding the theory and technologies to apply).*

Comment: This is really a very broad question, please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine learning task in question would not be the task of finding the best sport given already determined weights between questions and sports, it would be to find the weights given already answered questions and favorite sports.

Viz: You have a group of people (the training set) who have answered your questions and have then ranked their favorite sports using some scale (you pick).  Then, you train some algorithm to pick sports probabilistically to predict the results of the training set as closely as possible.

The attributes are not really useful if they already exist as questions (your indoor v outdoor example), and even then they are of questionable value.

For example, you fill out the questionairre: indoor v outdoor? o, gadget? y
Then you say how much you like various sports: soccer? 5, tennis? 8, bball? 2

From this your algorithm should determine that people who answer o,y like tennis, are indifferent to soccer, and hate basketball.  Of course, more data will produce more accurate results.

Probably the model to go with for modeling discrete inputs is a bayesian network.  You *can* include the attributes as an intermediate hidden layer in a bayesian network, but I would start with a simple bayesian network and then see if an intermediate layer adds value.  If you are confident that things like "using a ball" are really, in some sense, the *underlying reasons* that people like one sport v. another, then, yes, use a hidden layer in your network, otherwise, it's not going to be useful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this broad question.